# Incremental load from Big Query to Cloud MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am currently running a Cloud Function that exports an entire table in BigQuery  as csv files into Cloud Storage. From Cloud Storage I load the csv files into Cloud MySQL via the Cloud SQL Admin API. I run a truncate table statement for the table in MySQL before importing the csv files so the table in MySQL is rewritten each time the pipeline is run basically.

This is working fine for now but as the data volume increases, exporting and importing the entire table from BigQuery to Cloud MySQL might not be viable. I want to change the pipeline to only importing the new data from BigQuery into MySQL. I'm thinking of setting up a staging table in BigQuery, identify the MAX(Date) in the MySQL table A, insert into the staging table where table B.Date > MAX(table A.Date). Finally, export the staging table as csv files and import them into MySQL via the Cloud SQL Admin API.

How does this sound? Does anyone know if there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you perform only append in the BigQuery table? Or also update and deletion?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere Yes only append

Comment: You could work with append TVF feature https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-history#appends-tvf